# What collation does Evernote use for tags?

Tags: tags, collation, evernote

Evernote's tags are case-insensitive, but I've not been able to find a specification for exactly what collation or culture is used for this.

The Tag specification (https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Types.html#Struct_Tag) only states that "Case is preserved, but is ignored for comparisons."

Question: exactly what collation is being used?

**Note**: this is *not* a database question. This post has attracted answers that seem to automatically associate the term "collation" with databases. But this is an Evernote server-side data model question, and is best answered by Evernote experts or Evernote employees.

Comment: What do you mean by collation / culture?

Comment: Check the database table, here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-ways-to-backup-evernote-and-do-you-need-to/

Comment: open the evernote database with a db viewer (file location is in the link) and check the collation of the table/column.

Comment: Than your question makes no sense - there is mostly  no real collation in a c# or java or etc implementation, it exists only in the database.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. The question is about the EDAM data model and sync model and the underlying types. Please check your understanding of the term [collation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation). I'm very sure of what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Evernote seems to be using a custom collation called "NOCASEUTF8"

Ex :- Find unused tags in database. Sort by tag name.

```
SELECT * FROM tag_attr
WHERE note_count IS Null
ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE
```

The "COLLATE NOCASE" is required to avoid a "no such collation sequence: NOCASEUTF8" error

Comment: The question is not about the database, but the data model used on the Evernote server and Evernote clients. 

Tags are collated and duplicates are removed before anything else occurs, which includes saving tags in the database. For example you can see this by trying to create a tag named "FOOD" in Evernote when one named "food" already exists - the new tag is not created at all. The database is not even involved here. This is *not* a database question.